# Python - access Class_A object created and processed in a function of Class_B

Tags: python, class, object

I have two classes: Vehicle() and Route_plan() as follows:

```
class Vehicle():
def __init__(self,unique_id):
    self.capacity = 9000
    self.unique_id = unique_id
    self.routes = []

class Plan():
    def assignment(self):
        # create a vehicle as 'this_vehicle' with id = 0 from class Vehicle()
        this_vehicle = Vehicle(0)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(5)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(8)

#run the route_plan process to assgin the specfic routes to vehicle 0
Plan().assignment()

output: [5,8]
```

Now, I have another drawing function to try to plot the routes of each vehicle (in this case the vehicle 0):

```
def Draw():
    # if I have 10 vehicles (with id = 0,1,....9), how do I access them and their updated routes? 
    # Is there a simple way to update the vehicle's own variable (routes) directly using the vehicle ID and have it being flexibly called by any other classes and functions?
    # plotting process
```

Comment: At the moment you don't assign the `Plan` instance to anything or store the `Vehicle` beyond a local variable within the method, so: you **can't** get access to it.

Comment: Call `Plan().assignment()` in `Draw()` function

Comment: could you give an example for storing the Vehicle in Plan class?

Comment: @ThatBird even then `assignment` doesn't actually *return* the `Vehicle` instance, so it won't be accessible outside the method.

Comment: I'd recommend reading basic tutorials on OOP in Python, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: @ThatBird I want to access to the updated attributes of each/ or a specific vehicle after their processing in Plan().

Comment: Then you will probably have to persist all the `id`s that you pass to `Vehicle()` instances as well as it's output in some kind of database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have assignment(self) return this_vehicle, then use Plan().assignment() within Draw().

Eg:

```
class Plan():
    def assignment(self):
        # create a vehicle as 'this_vehicle' with id = 0 from class Vehicle()
        this_vehicle = Vehicle(0)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(5)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(8)

        return this_vehicle

def Draw():
    vehicle0 = Plan().assignment()
    # whatever else you want to do
```

Alternatively, store the vehicle within the Plan class.

```
class Plan():
    def assignment(self):
        # create a vehicle as 'this_vehicle' with id = 0 from class Vehicle()
        self.this_vehicle = Vehicle(0)
        self.this_vehicle.routes.append(5)
        self.this_vehicle.routes.append(8)

def Draw():
    route_plan = Plan()
    route_plan.assignment()
    # route_plan.this_vehicle now holds vehicle0
    # whatever else you want to do
```

Multiple Vehicles:
For this, you'll have to restructure Plan a little, although i feel this is getting a little messy, a dictionary is probably best here.

```
class Plan():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vehicles = dict()

    def assignment(self, id):
        # create a vehicle as 'this_vehicle' with id = 0 from class Vehicle()
        self.vehicles[id] = Vehicle(id)
        self.vehicles[id].routes.append(5)
        self.vehicles[id].routes.append(8)

def Draw():
    route_plan = Plan()
    route_plan.assignment(0)

    # route_plan.vehicles[0] now holds vehicle0
    # whatever else you want to do
```

Comment: if I have 10 vehicles (with id = 0,1,....9), how do I access them and their updated routes?

Comment: Updated answer, although this is getting a little messy, since you're now holding the id in two separate places, but there's no other logical way to do it nicely here.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. report 'NameError: name 'self' is not defined'. Even when I add a constructor for self.vehicles = dict() the output shows 'None'

Comment: My bad, did a dumb thing, that should have been created within the __init__ function (edited answer again).

Comment: after running the Draw() and print(Vehicle(0).routes), I still get empty list for Vehicle 0

Comment: That's not how you access it - the vehicles are held within the Plan class, so must be accessed from an object instance of that class, i.e. route_plan in this case. route_plan.vehicles[id] will return your vehicle object, or if you want to access the vehicles from outside of Draw() then return route_plan from Draw, and once again use that object.vehicles[id] to access the relevant vehicle object.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. As I could understand from your method, we basically create a new variable (vehicle dictionary) in Plan() Class to hold vehicles from Vehicle() Class. But I would want to know if there is more direct way for updating/accessing the vehicle's own variables (e.g. routes), regardless of where it is created and updated. If I have to update (vehicles.routes) in many different classes and functions, it will get complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176223/discussion-between-magnetron-and-jack).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self,unique_id):
        self.capacity = 9000
        self.unique_id = unique_id
        self.routes = []

class Plan(object):

    @staticmethod
    def assignment():
        # create a vehicle as 'this_vehicle' with id = 0 from class Vehicle()
        this_vehicle = Vehicle(0)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(5)
        this_vehicle.routes.append(8)

        return this_vehicle
# This list will save all of objects created by vehicle class and you can
# change their attributes when ever you want 
vehicles_list = []
def Draw():
    vehicle = Plan.assignment()
    vehicles_list.append(vehicle)
    # now you have Your routes and you can complete Your plotting code
    # for example now you can change first vehicle routes  in this way:
    # vehicles_list[0].routes[0] = 6
```

Comment: If You have for example 10 vehicles You have to save them in different variables when they are returning by assignment function, if You don't assign them to any variable it's not possible to use and manipulate then

Comment: you mean creating new variables in class plan() to store each unique vehicle?(that seems to be duplication work for me) Is there a simple way to update the vehicle's own variable (routes) and have it being called by any other classes and functions?

Comment: No i mean declare some thing like a list in main body of Your code ( outside of classes and functions) and append all of vehicle objects there then manipulate them whenever you want. see my updated answer

Comment: that's what I did before and i but I dont like this method. Cannot understand why we cannot easily pull out the attributes from a object once it is created (no matter where it is created and updated)

Comment: Ok maybe you need to study object oriented programming, it seems You're not familiar with it enough, be lucky !